# How to remove extended ASCII chars from SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ascii, collation, non-ascii-characters

So trying to remove all the extended ascii characters and used collation SQL_Latin1_General_CP1253_CI_AI in the ddl but still getting ascii characters. Is there any suggestion ?

I have a value stored in the sql as 'àccõrd' and i want it to be stored as accord. When i try select àccõrd collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1253_CI_AI it works but when i load it still gets loaded as àccõrd

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and a full explanation of what are you doing and what the difficulty is

Comment: If you're trying to remove non-ASCII characters why is it a problem to still have ASCII characters? Please edit your question with some example data, the code you're trying to use, the actual results and your expected results.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways to achieve what you're trying to do...

First method: define the column with a specific collation, e.g.:

```sql
create table dbo.Foo (
  FooName varchar(50) collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1253_CI_AI
);
insert dbo.Foo (FooName) values ('àccõrd');
select FooName from dbo.Foo;
```

Which yields:

```
FooName
-------
accord
```

Second method: collate the text when inserting it into your table:

```sql
-- Display the SQL Server instance's "default collation," configured during setup.
-- e.g.: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
select serverproperty('collation') as ServerCollation;

-- Display the current database's "default collation," configured in CREATE DATABASE.
-- e.g.: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
select collation_name
from sys.databases
where [name]=db_name();

create table dbo.Bar (
  BarName varchar(50) --database default: collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
);
insert dbo.Bar (BarName) values ('àccõrd' collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1253_CI_AI);
select BarName from dbo.Bar;
```

Which yields:

```
BarName
-------
accord
```

NOTE: These collation tricks only work with `char` and `varchar` data types.